# How to turn "abc.exe" to abc in Command Line

Tags: command-line, love2d

I want to run this command line: `"C:\Program Files\LOVE\love.exe" "C:\games\mygame"`
But it's too long, can i turn this into: `love "C:\games\mygame"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `C:\Program Files\LOVE\` to the PATH environment variable. This way, the command can be found from the commandline without explicitly specifying the path.

See https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them on what environment variables are and how to set them in Windows.